# transfer data between 2 fragments of a TabLayout Android Studio

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, android-tablayout

So I have an app with a TabLayout. In there, I created 2 tabs (fragments).My first fragment is OngletCours and the 2nd one OngletNotes.

I have a ListView in the first tab/fragment. I would like to transfer the Item I clicked in that ListView to the 2nd Fragment to a TextView.

I have already tried something but I get a NullPointerException at line 23:

> 03-06 09:38:32.874 23677-23677/com.example.dasilvadd.students E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                   java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                       at com.example.dasilvadd.students.OngletNotes.onCreateView(OngletNotes.java:23)

here's the code from my 1st tab **OngletCours** (Only the setOnItemClickListener):

```
    final ListView l1 = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ListCours);

    l1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            OngletNotes fragment = ((Onglets)getActivity()).getOngletNotes ();
            if(fragment != null) {
             l1.getItemAtPosition(i);
                //Put the value
                OngletNotes onotes = new OngletNotes();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString("Item","l1.getItemAtPosition(i)");
                onotes.setArguments(args);
               getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, onotes).commit();
            }
                ((Onglets)getActivity()).goToFragment(1);
        }
    });  
    return rootView;
    }
```

Here's the code from my 2nd tab **OngletNotes**:

```
public class OngletNotes extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ongletnotes, container, false);
    //where i want to insert the selectedItem
    TextView Cours = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.TVCours);
    //Retrieve the value
     //THE ERROR IS HERE !
   String cours = getArguments().getString("Item");
    Cours.setText(cours);
    return rootView;
}

public static OngletNotes newInstance() {
    OngletNotes fragment = new OngletNotes();

    return fragment;
}
```

So, I don't know how to transfer the selected Item into the 2nd tab.
Do I have to create methodes in my TabbedActivity called **Onglets**? Please tell me if you need the code for that class as well.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got a bit confused in your logic. You are checking for null and then not doing anything if the fragment is null.

You can simplify it like this:
First check if fragment is null , if so create a new instance, then
put the arguments outside the if/else so you make sure you get them every time.
Also put your string item in a variable.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    OngletNotes fragment = ((Onglets)getActivity()).getOngletNotes ();
    if(fragment == null) {
        fragment = OngletNotes.getInstance();
    }
    String item = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
    //Put the value
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("Item",item);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
}
```

Comment: I got this error : Error:(125, 51) error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to String

In String item = l1.getItemAtPosition(i)

Comment: try adding toString();

Comment: I got the same error at the begining here : `String cours = getArguments().getString("Item");` NullPointerException..

Comment: OK show the code where you define your ListAdapter.

Comment: `listeCours = dbhelper.getAllCours();
            String item;
            String[] cours = {""};

            arrayList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(cours));

            final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                    (getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);

            l1.setAdapter(adapter);
            for (int i = 0; i < listeCours.size(); i++) {          
                item = listeCours.get(i).getCours();
         
                arrayList.add(item);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: The ListView works well, but I'm still not able to transfer the selected Item to the 2nd tab..

Comment: Sorry , cant seem to find the problem here either , if you upload your full code somewhere ( like github) I can take a look at it.

Comment: Here it is my full code as you asked : 

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/david-silva987/4a6f646b3dded534dc946cd57958c7f3/raw/d1c350735ec123194c31a6d58fd9a0be1ec9ba5e/Android